# How to add css to override existing styling in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, slds, styleclass, design-attributes

I am using an existing lightning component that displays some checkboxes. I am wondering if there is a way to reduce the size of the checkboxes.

```
<design:component >

   <design:attribute name="childCheckbox1_label" label="Label Checkbox 1 "/>
   <design:attribute name="childCheckbox1_storage" label="Checkbox 1 Output 
   Value"/>
   <design:attribute name="childCheckbox1_defaultValue" label="Checkbox 1 
   Default Value"/>

  <design:attribute name="childCheckbox2_label" label="Label Checkbox 2 "/>
  <design:attribute name="childCheckbox2_storage" label="Checkbox 2 Output 
  Value "/>
  <design:attribute name="childCheckbox2_defaultValue" label="Checkbox 2 
  Default Value"/>


</design:component>
```

I checked the code using inspect element. Found out this piece of code.

slds-form-element_stacked:not([class*="slds-size"]), .slds-form_stacked 
.slds-form-element:not([class*="slds-size"]), .slds-form_horizontal .slds- 
form-element_stacked:not([class*="slds-size"])

{  width: 100%; 
     flex-basis: 100%; }

The width above is set to 100%. I need to change the width somehow in the above code. I tried to add the following in style class but it does not work.

.THIS.slds-form-element_stacked .slds-form_stacked .slds-form_horizontal { width: 3%; flex-basis: 100%; }

Answer (score 0):

Create a .css file associated to the Aura Component (Ctrl+Shift+4 `STYLE` option in the Developer Console when you opened a Lightning Aura Component) and then adjust the CSS as you please.

Refer here (in the [Aura CSS Becomes Standard CSS](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning-web-components-for-aura-developers/migrate-markup-and-css) section) to an example of how the CSS looks in an Aura component.

Sample taken from that link:

```
.THIS .lower-third {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    padding: 6px 8px;
}
.THIS .lower-third > p {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.THIS .truncate {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I guess I am struggling with how to reference checkboxes in style class. Tried this    .THIS .childCheckbox1{
    width:20%;
    
}

It didn't work.

Comment: Please note that `.THIS.className` and `.THIS .className` with a space in between makes a big difference.  If the root of your component is just a checkbox, then you need to use `.THIS.className`.  As for getting the CSS right, try inspecting the element in Google Chrome and adjust the CSS on the checkbox.  Find what works and then adjust the aura components .css file

Comment: Also, I don't think you can adjust the CSS on `.design` attributes that are seen from the Lightning App Builder - not sure from your question if that's what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: I am using lightning component inside a visual/lightning flow to display the dynamic questions. Here is the link to the lightning component:
https://github.com/alexed1/LightningFlowComponents/tree/master/flow_screen_components/dynamicQuestionFSC

Comment: I inspected the element in chrome and was able to track the issue. Width was set to 100%. When I unchecked it in console it worked. But when I refreshed the page, changes are not saved. Here is the code: How do I add it in CSS class? 

.slds-form-element_stacked:not([class*="slds-size"]), .slds-form_stacked .slds-form-element:not([class*="slds-size"]), .slds-form_horizontal .slds-form-element_stacked:not([class*="slds-size"]) {
    /* width: 100%; */
    flex-basis: 100%;
}

Comment: You'll have to play around with the .css aura component file.  Try using `!important` on some of the width adjustments to see if you can bypass that 100% width issue

Comment: .THIS.slds-form-element_stacked .slds-form_stacked .slds-form_horizontal  {
    width: 3%;
    flex-basis: 100%;
}

I edited the above code in style class, it didn't work.

Comment: I suggest editing your original question with some of the adjustments you've made (include code examples) and see if others in the community can help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93011/discussion-between-student-and-brian-miller).